# Calculating height and width of Vue slots

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having trouble calculating the height and width of slots.  I am trying to render images in my Perimeter component. These images have a size 105x160.  However, when I console.log the clientWidth and clientHeight, I get 0x24.

I believe my problem is related to this: [In vue.js 2, measure the height of a component once slots are rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997488/in-vue-js-2-measure-the-height-of-a-component-once-slots-are-rendered) but I still can't figure it out. I've tried using $nextTick on both the Perimeter component and the individual slot components.

In my Perimeter component, I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <slot></slot>
    <div class="align-self-center">
      <slot name="center-piece"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Perimeter',
    mounted() {
      this.distributeSlots();
    },
    updated() {
      this.distributeSlots();
    },
    computed: {
      centerRadius() {
        return this.$slots['center-piece'][0].elm.clientWidth / 2;
      },
    },
    methods: {
      distributeSlots() {
        let angle = 0;
        const {
          clientHeight: componentHeight,
          clientWidth: componentWidth,
          offsetTop: componentOffsetTop,
          offsetLeft: componentOffsetLeft,
        } = this.$el;
        const componentXCenter = componentWidth / 2;
        const componentYCenter = componentHeight / 2;

        const slots = this.$slots.default.filter(slot => slot.tag) || [];
        const step = (2 * Math.PI) / slots.length;

        slots.forEach((slot) => {
          slot.context.$nextTick(() => {
            const { height, width } = slot.elm.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log(`height ${height}, width ${width}`);
            const distanceFromCenterX = (this.centerRadius + componentXCenter) * Math.cos(angle);
            const distanceFromCenterY = (this.centerRadius + componentYCenter) * Math.sin(angle);
            const x = Math.round((componentXCenter + distanceFromCenterX + componentOffsetLeft) - (width / 2));
            const y = Math.round((componentYCenter + distanceFromCenterY + componentOffsetTop) - (height / 2));

            slot.elm.style.left = `${x}px`;
            slot.elm.style.top = `${y}px`;

            angle += step;
          });
        });
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

I also had my distributeSlots() method written without $nextTick:

```
distributeSlots() {
  let angle = 0;
  const {
    clientHeight: componentHeight,
    clientWidth: componentWidth,
    offsetTop: componentOffsetTop,
    offsetLeft: componentOffsetLeft,
  } = this.$el;
  const componentXCenter = componentWidth / 2;
  const componentYCenter = componentHeight / 2;

  const slots = this.$slots.default.filter(slot => slot.tag) || [];
  const step = (2 * Math.PI) / slots.length;

  slots.forEach((slot) => {
    const { height, width } = slot.elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    const distanceFromCenterX = (this.centerRadius + componentXCenter) * Math.cos(angle);
    const distanceFromCenterY = (this.centerRadius + componentYCenter) * Math.sin(angle);
    const x = Math.round((componentXCenter + distanceFromCenterX + componentOffsetLeft) - (width / 2));
    const y = Math.round((componentYCenter + distanceFromCenterY + componentOffsetTop) - (height / 2));

    slot.elm.style.left = `${x}px`;
    slot.elm.style.top = `${y}px`;

    angle += step;
  });
},
```

I am passing to the Perimeter component as follows:

```
<template>
  <perimeter>
    <div v-for="(book, index) in books.slice(0, 6)" v-if="book.image" :key="book.asin" style="position: absolute">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'books', params: { isbn: book.isbn }}">
        <img :src="book.image" />
      </router-link>
    </div>
  <perimeter>
</template>
```

Even worse, when I console.log(slot.elm) in the forEach function and open up the array in the browser console, I see the correct clientHeight + clientWidth:

[image: ClientHeight and ClientWidth when slot.elm logged and expanded]

Answer (score 4):

Usually in such cases it's a logical mistake, rather than an issue with the framework. So I would go with simplifying your code to the bare minimum that demonstrates your issue.

Assuming you get `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` on `mounted()` or afterwards, as demonstarted below, it should just work.

**Avoid any timer hacks, they are the culprit for bugs that are extremely hard to debug.**

```
<template>
  <div style="min-height: 100px; min-width: 100px;">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyContainer',
  data (){
    return {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    }
  },
  mounted (){
    this.width = this.$slots["default"][0].elm.clientWidth
    this.height = this.$slots["default"][0].elm.clientHeight
    console.log(this.width, this.height)  // => 100 100 (or more)
  },

}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use a trick and put the code in a `setTimeout` method to execute it in another thread with a tiny delay:

```
setTimeout(() => {
     // Put your code here
     ...
}, 80)
```

Comment: This is an unreliable hack and doesn't solve the issue at hand.

Comment: Yes it is, but it was worth mentioning.

Comment: what if actually the DOM update takes longer than 80ms?